# SSRS drop down and input parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, multivalue

I am creating an SSRS report in Visual Studio 2008 and I was wondering if it is possible to have a drop down parameter that also allows user input. I have done a lot of research and haven't found anything that talks about this issue.

I have a multi-value drop down parameter that is populated through a query. I would like my user to be able to input a new value and use that along with the other values that are already populated in the drop down menu.

Any help and/or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You should create something in DOTNET such as a form or such in ASP.NET, WinForms, or WPF.  Anything but SSRS which is an output only design as should mostly all reporting products be, no matter what the framework.  When you start trying to put input in what should be output that is a slippery slope you don't want to go down IMHO.

Comment: I am required to use SSRS as I am creating a report for work and this is the platform they request! @djangojazz

Comment: You should not be required to be putting in input though in reporting.    Use WPF, ASP.NET, HTML, or WinForms or something MEANT for input.  You are trying to put a square peg in a round hole using reporting for input.  You could do it, doing it is horrid in coding standards using an output framework for input.

Comment: I'm sorry but like I said I cannot. I am creating reports that require users to select/input parameters to populate the report. I am required to use SSRS so I am trying to figure this all out. I understand it may not be the easiest/best way to do things but I am stuck doing things this way. @djangojazz what would be your suggestion using SSRS regardless of the standards?

Comment: 'Use WPF, ASP.NET, HTML, or WinForms or something MEANT for input.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new Parameter before the existing multi-value parameter.  This would be a single-value with no associated dataset.

Then in the current query driving the multi-value parameter, I would add a UNION ALL clause to add a single row for the input value.

Comment: how would I add a single row for input code like this:
UNION SELECT @singleParameter ?
Sorry I am semi-new to SSRS and SQL

Comment: This does work but it requires me to input a new value before the other parameter populates.... I don't think every time the user will want to input a parameter. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it so that my user can input multiple values? This solution does not work for this case... only works for single parameters

Comment: For multiple values you would need to pass the singleParameter into a stored procedure that updates a list table and returns the results for the mult-value parameter.

Comment: You can give a parameter a default value, that way the multi-value parameter will appear immediately. You could filter out that default value e.g. `UNION ALL SELECT @singleParameter WHERE @singleParameter <> 'Default'`

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this as soon as possible!